# MVC5 accessing Action/Controller with ActionResult gets skipped and produces "The resource cannot be found" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, action

I have a MVC5 view that has a form on the page that submits to a background process in the /Account Controller. I have 4 others pages that are very similar with ActionResult but they just return a view without any other logic. Does anyone have any ideas on where I went wrong? Ive looked through several similar errors but none touch on what I am experiencing.

### HTML/RAZOR FORM

```
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Process", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                        <input placeholder="Card number" type="text" name="number" class="form-control">
                        <input placeholder="Full name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                        <input placeholder="MM/YY" type="text" name="expiry" class="form-control">
                        <input placeholder="CVC" type="text" name="cvc" class="form-control">
                    }
```

### CONTROLLER

```
    //POST: Process
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Process()
    {
        try
            {
                var myCustomer = new StripeCustomerCreateOptions();

                // set these properties if it makes you happy
                myCustomer.Email = "pork@email.com";
                myCustomer.Description = "Johnny Tenderloin (pork@email.com)";

                // set this property if using a token
                //myCustomer.TokenId = *tokenId*;

                // set these properties if passing full card details (do not
                // set these properties if you have set TokenId)
                myCustomer.CardNumber = "4242424242424242";
                myCustomer.CardExpirationYear = "2012";
                myCustomer.CardExpirationMonth = "10";
                myCustomer.CardAddressCountry = "US";                // optional
                myCustomer.CardAddressLine1 = "24 Beef Flank St";    // optional
                myCustomer.CardAddressLine2 = "Apt 24";              // optional
                myCustomer.CardAddressCity = "Biggie Smalls";        // optional
                myCustomer.CardAddressState = "NC";                  // optional
                myCustomer.CardAddressZip = "27617";                 // optional
                myCustomer.CardName = "Joe Meatballs";               // optional
                myCustomer.CardCvc = "1223";                         // optional


                //myCustomer.PlanId = *planId*;                          // only if you have a plan
                //myCustomer.Coupon = *couponId*;                        // only if you have a coupon
                myCustomer.TrialEnd = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1);    // when the customers trial ends (overrides the plan if applicable)
                myCustomer.Quantity = 1;                               // optional, defaults to 1

                var customerService = new StripeCustomerService();
                StripeCustomer stripeCustomer = customerService.Create(myCustomer);

                var myCharge = new StripeChargeCreateOptions();

                // always set these properties
                myCharge.Amount = 5153;
                myCharge.Currency = "usd";

                // set this if you want to
                myCharge.Description = "Charge it like it's hot";

                // set this property if using a token
                //myCharge.TokenId = *tokenId*;

                // set these properties if passing full card details
                // (do not set these properties if you have set a TokenId)
                myCharge.CardNumber = "4242424242424242";
                myCharge.CardExpirationYear = "2012";
                myCharge.CardExpirationMonth = "10";
                myCharge.CardAddressCountry = "US";               // optional
                myCharge.CardAddressLine1 = "24 Beef Flank St";   // optional
                myCharge.CardAddressLine2 = "Apt 24";             // optional
                myCharge.CardAddressState = "NC";                 // optional
                myCharge.CardAddressZip = "27617";                // optional
                myCharge.CardName = "Joe Meatballs";              // optional
                myCharge.CardCvc = "1223";                        // optional

                // set this property if using a customer
                myCharge.CustomerId = "E2G1";

                // if using a customer, you may also set this property to charge
                // a card other than the customer's default card
                //myCharge.Card = *cardId*;

                // set this if you have your own application fees (you must have your application configured first within Stripe)
                //myCharge.ApplicationFee = 25;

                // (not required) set this to false if you don't want to capture the charge yet - requires you call capture later
                myCharge.Capture = true;

                var chargeService = new StripeChargeService();
                StripeCharge stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(myCharge);

                return View("SignupPaySuccess", "Home");
            }
        catch
            {
                return View("SignupPayDecline","Account");
            }
    }
```

### ERROR SCREEN

[image: Error Screen FireFox]
Thanks a ton for your help!

CSSHell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indicate a parameter in your action method so that the router can correctly direct your 'post' to an action method with a parameter to bind the posted data.

If you create a model class like:

```
public class ProcessModel
{
   public string number {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
   public string expiry {get; set;}
   public string cvc {get; set;}
}
```

and then change your action method signature from

```
public ActionResult Process()
```

to

```
public ActionResult Process(ProcessModel process)
```

the router should correctly identify the correct endpoint to route to.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance. After trying the above, I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using areas? if so, try something like this:

```
Html.BeginForm("Process", "Account", new {area="name-of-the-area"})
```

Comment: I am not using areas. After looking at areas it seems that I should have started down that path but I am too far along at this point. It is the exact same code as every other ActionResult with exception to the async Task<actionResult> items. It should work.